# DevExpress create Dynamic grouping of columns

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have the following data structure:

```
public class Person {
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public List<Finance> {get;set;}
}

public class Finance{
       public string Name{get;set;}
       public decimal GrossValue{get;set;}
       public decimal NettValue{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to show the data in a grid as follows

Columns
  Name(From Person)         Name(From Finance as a Group)
                               Gross Value        NettValue

```
Names Of People              Gross Value         NettValue
```

So it could possibly look like this:

```
 Name                           Jan                     Feb              Mar
                             Gross    Nett             Gross   Nett     Gross    Nett
   Joe                        100      50              1000    200        200     10
   Jill                      1000      900              450     11       2220      110
```

ETC...

Can this be done in DevExpress WinForms Grid if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with an XtraGrid, but the approach would require unbound or calculated columns.  The [XtraPivotGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Pivot_Grid/) control would usually be a better choice for this sort of thing.